# How to override Web service url in http request node in IIB

Tags: ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I'm trying to override the default `RequestURL` on an HTTP request node in an IIB request flow but it doesn't work.
I have tried setting the following value in a computation esql node before I call the "request node" but it doesn't work.

> ```
> SET OutputLocalEnvironment.Destination.HTTP.RequestURL = 'http://mytseturl.com/sadf'
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Check a Compute Mode property for used compute node. It must consists LocalEnvironment. More about Compute Mode here - [Setting the mode](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac04660_.html?view=kc#ac04660_mode)

Answer (score 0):

Double Click on the HTTP request node and insert the URL.